# An event in LoadData method not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Situation :

- i have two classes in viewmodels : MedicineModel and MedicineData .
- i have a event Event1 which i fire at the end of LoadData method located in MedcineModel.cs .
- this event is then handled in MainPage.xaml.cs , where event handler
  points to a secific method  i want to execute .

Problem:

- The problem is that Event1 is not firing .

This is code of app.xaml.cs

```
private static MedicineModel viewModel = null;
    public static MedicineModel  ViewModel {

        get
        {
            if (viewModel==null)
            {
                viewModel = new MedicineModel();
                viewModel.LoadData();
            }
            return viewModel;
        }

    }
```

The code for MedicineModel.cs is

```
namespace MedicinePlus.ViewModels
{
public delegate void EventDelegate();
public class MedicineModel
{
    public List<MedicineData> Problems { get; set; }
    public MedicineModel()
    {
        this.Problems = new List<MedicineData>();
    }

    public bool IsDataLoaded { get; set; }
    public event EventDelegate Event1;
    public void LoadData()
    {
    //place rt time Data here
        IsDataLoaded = true;
        this.Problems.Add(new MedicineData() { ID = 0, ProblemName = "Fever"});
        this.Problems.Add(new MedicineData(){ID=1,ProblemName="Diarrhea"});
        this.Problems.Add(new MedicineData() { ID=2,ProblemName = "sprain"});
        this.Problems.Add(new MedicineData() { ID = 3, ProblemName = "bruise" });

        OnEvent1();
    }

   protected virtual void OnEvent1()
   {
       EventDelegate handler = Event1;
       if (handler!=null)
       {
           handler();
       }
   }
}
}
```

and The code of MainPage.xaml.cs is

where textListViewSource is a name of collection view source and listBoxTextItems is the name of listBox

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;

        App.ViewModel.Event1 += new EventDelegate(eventHandler);

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    private void eventHandler()
    {             
        textListViewSource.Source = App.ViewModel.Problems;
        listBoxTextItems.DataContext = App.ViewModel.Problems;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's see the workflow of your app:

1. You're accessing the `App.ViewModel` property, to retrieve the viewmodel and assign it to your datacontext
2. In the getter of the `App.ViewModel` property, you instantiate the viewmodel, and call the `LoadData` method
3. In the `LoadData` method, you load your data (obviously), then raise the `Event1` event
4. The getter finishes to execute, you retrieve your instance of the viewmodel
5. You subscribe to the `Event1` event

Following those steps, there's no way that the `Event1` event would be raised in `MainPage`, since you're subscribing **after** it has been raised.

Comment: Then what do i do if i want to raise `Event1` in `MainPage` , so that `eventHandler` gets executed whenever `MainPage.xaml` is loaded ?

Comment: @user3442701 What's the point in having an event that is going to be raised the second the type is created?  Rather than attaching the handler, the method that would be attached could just be called directly.

Answer (score -1):

I have uploaded the working test project here - http://1drv.ms/NOvNSd. It is a WPF project based on your classes, but you can easily take the code from this and put it in your Windows Phone project.